# The best way to do permission set in Django (group, roles, permissions)

Tags: sql, django, database-design, architecture, permissions

Thanks for reading my question.

Before to ask, i was reading about my doubt:

http://djangobook.com/customizing-authentication-django/

[django roles authorization architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134674/django-roles-authorization-architecture)

[Django Permissions for Different Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641392/django-permissions-for-different-clients)

... And i'm not clear about permissions set in Django :(

I learning Django, but i want to try to build a permission set on my app. My system is about a schoool: teachers, students, management people, class room leaders.

The system's premise is: an user only must to have a rol.

Some questions about it:

1. I thinking to prepopulate role table, with general profiles: student, teacher, management... What is the better way to do it?
2. The typical restriction: a teacher is the unique profile can add, delete, view, edit your student's scores. What is the better way to do it? Should I do it through a custom system? Have u some url, code or source where can i to check it?

Excuse me my english. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and ended up designing my own permission system, because with the default django permission system, it is not possible to do per-object permissions.

I simply added a model LabAccess with a foreign key on django.contrib.auth.models.Group (because I often have multiple instructors by course) and another foreign key for the course. (This allows multiple groups be instructor in a course). Then, in each view for instructors, I check whether one of the groups the user belongs to has an item in the LabAccess table. The source code of this system is actually [available](https://gitlab.cosy.sbg.ac.at/wmann/inhander), if you are interested.

Note that there are also django extensions that support per-object permissions, like (django-guardian) http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable. (I have no experience with it,)

Comment: Hello @W.Mann, thank u for ur answer and link, it's so cool! I think... if for my basics requirements Django can't do it in native way, Is django the correct framework to do my system? i don't know...

Comment: @Sommer: If you know django already and the roles/permissions are not too complicated, you will probably be best served with django, Note that there are also django extensions that support per-object permissions, like [django-guardian](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).(no experience with it, but I will add it to my answer) BTW: Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: thank u again! Going to try to build my permissions system on Django.

Comment: A question about ur answer: what is the difference between Django permission system and Django-guardian? Rhanks!

Comment: @W.Mann Hi, i would like you invite you to my project that has this exact problem to solve, If you are interested in a freelance gig, please mail me at anonvivek[at]gmail[dot]in

Comment: could you offer requirements file please ?